# error: ‘Default’ is not a member of ‘ns3::YansWifiPhyHelper’

Tags: c++, ubuntu-20.04, ns-3

I'm learning ns-3 on a virtual machine with ubuntu linux 20.04 and ns-3.35. I wrote in c++.
The yans-wifi-helper.h is included in my file.
And I wrote a line as below.

`YansWifiPhyHelper phy = YansWifiPhyHelper::Default();`

But when compiling

```
root@kotoridsk233-vm:/home/kotoridsk233/ns3_install/ns-allinone-3.35/ns-3.35# ./waf
Waf: Entering directory /home/kotoridsk233/ns3_install/ns-allinone-3.35/ns-3.35/build'
[2968/3038] Compiling scratch/try.cc
../scratch/try.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
../scratch/try.cc:30:46: error: ‘Default’ is not a member of ‘ns3::YansWifiPhyHelper’
   30 |   YansWifiPhyHelper phy = YansWifiPhyHelper::Default();
      |                                              ^~~~~~~
Waf: Leaving directory /home/kotoridsk233/ns3_install/ns-allinone-3.35/ns-3.35/build'
Build failed
 -> task in 'try' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more information)
```

However, I read the doc of ns3::YansWifiPhyHelper. Default is one of the static public member functions.

My whole code is as below.(not finish yet)

```
#include "ns3/core-module.h"
#include "ns3/point-to-point-module.h"
#include "ns3/network-module.h"
#include "ns3/applications-module.h"
#include "ns3/mobility-module.h"
#include "ns3/csma-module.h"
#include "ns3/internet-module.h"
#include "ns3/yans-wifi-helper.h"
#include "ns3/ssid.h"

using namespace ns3;

NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE ("trytodohomework");

int 
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  CommandLine cmd;
  cmd.Parse (argc, argv);
  
  Time::SetResolution (Time::NS);
  LogComponentEnable ("UdpEchoClientApplication", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
  LogComponentEnable ("UdpEchoServerApplication", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);

  NodeContainer wifinodes;
  wifinodes.Create (100);

  YansWifiChannelHelper channel = YansWifiChannelHelper::Default();
  YansWifiPhyHelper phy = YansWifiPhyHelper::Default();
  phy.SetPcapDataLinkType (WifiPhyHelper::DLT_IEEE802_11_RADIO);
  phy.SetChannel (channel.Create());

  WifiHelper wifi; 
  wifi.SetRemoteStationManager ("ns3::IdealWifiManager");
  WifiMacHelper mac;

  NetDeviceContainer WifiDevice;
  Ssid ssid;
  ssid = Ssid ("wifi-network");
  phy.Set ("ChannelNumber", UintegerValue (36));
  mac.SetType ("ns3::StaWifiMac",
               "QosSupported", BooleanValue (true),
               "Ssid", SsidValue (ssid));
  WifiDevice = wifi.Install (phy, mac, wifinodes.Get (0));

  MobilityHelper mobility;
  mobility.SetPositionAllocator ("ns3::GridPositionAllocator",
                              "MinX", DoubleValue (0.0),
                              "MinY", DoubleValue (0.0),
                              "DeltaX", DoubleValue (100),
                              "DeltaY", DoubleValue (100),
                              "GridWidth", UintegerValue (1000),
                              "LayoutType", StringValue ("RowFirst"));

  mobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");
  mobility.Install(wifinodes);

  InternetStackHelper stack;
  stack.Install (wifinodes);

  Ipv4AddressHelper address;
  address.SetBase ("10.1.1.0", "255.255.255.0");
  Ipv4InterfaceContainer WifiInterface;
  WifiInterface = address.Assign (WifiDevice);

  uint16_t port = 9;
  UdpEchoServerHelper wifiserver (port);
  ApplicationContainer wifiserverApp = wifiserver.Install (wifinodes.Get (0));
  wifiserverApp.Start (Seconds (1.0));
  wifiserverApp.Stop (Seconds (100.0));

  UdpEchoClientHelper echoClient (WifiInterface.GetAddress(1),9);
  echoClient.SetAttribute ("DataRate", StringValue ("1000kb/s"));
  echoClient.SetAttribute ("MaxPackets", UintegerValue (1));
  echoClient.SetAttribute ("Interval", TimeValue (Seconds (1.0)));
  echoClient.SetAttribute ("PacketSize", UintegerValue (1048576));

  ApplicationContainer clientApps = echoClient.Install (wifinodes.Get(99));
  clientApps.Start (Seconds (1.0));
  clientApps.Stop (Seconds (100.0));

  Simulator::Run ();
  Simulator::Destroy ();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Re. `"However, I read the doc of ns3::YansWifiPhyHelper. Default is one of the static public member functions"`: please provide a reference.

Comment: [link](https://netdb.cis.upenn.edu/rapidnet/doxygen/html/classns3_1_1_yans_wifi_phy_helper.html)

Comment: That looks like old documentation (generated in 2010).  The [latest](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.35/doxygen/classns3_1_1_yans_wifi_phy_helper.html) doesn't mention any `Default` static member function.

Comment: thx for your help @G.M.